# Calculating complicated expectation

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

I need to calculate $\operatorname{E}( X_2 \mid X_1=x, Y=y)$, where $Y=\max\{X_2,X_3\}$ and joint density of $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ is given by:

$$f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x,y,z)=\frac{24}{25}(1+\frac{xyz}{3})$$
$x,y,z\in [0,1]$.

I completely don't know how can I tackle this problem. Please help me.

Comment: I would start by trying to find $\Pr(Y=X_2\mid X_1=x\ \&\ Y=y)$. The conditional distribution of $X_2$ given $X_1=x$ and $Y=y$ has a discrete part and a continuous part.  The foregoing probability gives you the discrete part. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Or perhaps you should first work on finding the conditional distribution of $(X_2,X_3)$ given $X_1=x$ and then find the probability I mention above. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach it is as follows. Firstly, $Y$ is either $X_2$ or $X_3$ and with equal probability because $f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}$ is symmetric wrt those two variables. So we begin by conditioning on the event that $X_2=Y$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X_2\mid X_1=x, Y=y) &=& E(X_2\mid X_1=x, Y=y, X_2=y)P(X_2=y\mid X_1=x, Y=y) + \\
&& E(X_2\mid X_1=x, Y=y, X_2\lt y)P(X_2\lt y\mid X_1=x, Y=y). \qquad\text{(1)}
\end{eqnarray*}

Now to evaluate these components. That $E(X_2\mid X_1=x, Y=y, X_2=y) = y\;$ is easy. And again, by symmetry of $f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}$, we have

$$P(X_2=y\mid X_1=x, Y=y) = \dfrac{1}{2} = P(X_2\lt y\mid X_1=x, Y=y).$$

It remains to find $E(X_2\mid X_1=x, Y=y, X_2\lt y)$ and we do so by firstly finding $P(X_2 = u\mid X_1=x, Y=y, X_2\lt y)$ for any $u \lt y$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X_2 = u\mid X_1=x, Y=y, X_2\lt y) &=& \dfrac{P(X_2 = u, X_1=x, Y=y, X_2\lt y)}{P(X_1=x, Y=y, X_2\lt y)} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{P(X_2 = u, X_1=x, X_3=y)}{P(X_1=x, X_3=y, X_2\lt y)}. \\
&& \\
P(X_2 = u, X_1=x, X_3=y) &=& f_{X_1,X_2,X_3}(x,u,y) \\
&=& \dfrac{24}{25}\left( 1 + \dfrac{xuy}{3} \right). \\
&& \\
P(X_1=x, X_3=y, X_2\lt y) &=& \int_{v=0}^{y} \dfrac{24}{25}\left( 1 + \dfrac{xvy}{3} \right)\;dv \\
&=& \dfrac{24}{25}\left[ v + \dfrac{xv^2y}{6} \right]_{v=0}^{y} \\
&=& \dfrac{24}{25}\left( y + \dfrac{xy^3}{6} \right). \\
&& \\
\therefore\quad P(X_2 = u\mid X_1=x, Y=y, X_2\lt y) &=& \dfrac{\dfrac{24}{25}\left( 1 + \dfrac{xuy}{3} \right)}{\dfrac{24}{25}\left( y + \dfrac{xy^3}{6} \right)} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{6 + 2xuy}{6y + xy^3}. \\
&& \\
\therefore\quad E(X_2\mid X_1=x, Y=y, X_2\lt y) &=& \int_{u=0}^{y} u P(X_2 = u\mid X_1=x, Y=y, X_2\lt y)\;du \\
&& \\
&=& \int_{u=0}^{y} \dfrac{6u + 2xu^2y}{6y + xy^3}\;du \\
&& \\
&=& \left[ \dfrac{3u^2 + \dfrac{2xu^3y}{3}}{6y + xy^3} \right]_{u=0}^{y} \\
&=& \dfrac{3y^2 + \dfrac{2xy^4}{3}}{6y + xy^3} \\
&=& \dfrac{9y + 2xy^3}{18 + 3xy^2}.\end{eqnarray*}

Returning to equation $(1)$, we now have,

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(X_2\mid X_1=x, Y=y) &=& \dfrac{1}{2} y + \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{9y + 2xy^3}{18 + 3xy^2} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{18y + 3xy^3 + 9y + 2xy^3}{36 + 6xy^2} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{27y + 5xy^3}{36 + 6xy^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank your for your effort. I really appreciate it

Comment: @luka5z Glad to help. :)